# How to properly convert byte array of UTF-16LE chars to utf-8 string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Base64 encoded binary of a packet capture.
I want to extract a substring at a certain position of the capture.

I'm doing this in Ruby:

```
payload_decoded = Base64.decode64(payload)
file_size = payload_decoded[114..115].unpack('S*')[0]
file_fullpath = payload_decoded[124, file_size]
p file_fullpath
```

This works to some extent. file_size gets an integer with the length I want to extract. I then can extract the correct slice of the byte array. And if I just test this in my Mac's terminal, it displays the string perfectly.

But, this code in the application itself, that runs in CentOS7, all characters are displayed suffixed with the 00 byte (e.g. T displays as T\x00). I guess I can just strip that out of the string, but would like to avoid that. What would be the most correct way to handle this?

TIA

Comment: Usually [`String#encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-encode) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I did try to use encode. But it was missing the force_encoding before it. What confused me more was that in the Mac terminal I just didn't need those extra steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to get the desired result:

```
file_fullpath = file_fullpath.force_encoding('UTF-16LE').encode!('UTF-8')
```

Seems like I first need to "convince" Ruby that the string is UTF-16LE, and only then convert to UTF-8.

Comment: Ruby String is a encoded byte array plus a encoding tag. The `encode` method relies on this encoding tag to convert the encoding properly.